# Cannot find a proper format for codec ‘h264’ (id 28), pixel format ‘none’

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, codec, nvidia-jetson-nano

I downloaded jocover’s git hub ffmpeg and compiled it to stream the video to the web on the Jetsonano board
However, i tried

```
ffmpeg -c:vh264_nvmpi -i /dev/video -f null -
```

> Cannot find a proper format for codec ‘h264’ (id 28), pixel format
> ‘none’ (id-1)
>
> Assertion *codec_id != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE failed at
> src/libavdevice/v4l2.c:811

I got this error

and I tried `./ffmpeg -encoders |grep 264`

As a result of this console, the output is as follows:

> v… h264_nvmpi nvmpi H.264 encoder wrapper (codec h264)

> v… h264_v4l2m2m V4L2 mem2mem H.264 encoder wrapper (codec h264)

> v… h264_vaapi H.264/AVC (VAAPI) (codec h264)

The camera specs are like this maybe Sony IMX219, a model called Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2

> ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
>
> Index : 0
>
> Type : Video Capture
>
> Pixel Format: ‘RG10’
>
> Name : 10-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB

I’d really appreciate your help

thx

Comment: What does `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -list_formats all /dev/video0` return? You need to look up the supported configurations using this command [ref](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#video4linux2_002c-v4l2)

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but there is a missing **space**. Replace `ffmpeg -c:vh264_nvmpi -i /dev/video -f null -` with `ffmpeg -c:v h264_nvmpi -i /dev/video -f null -`